# add default option to ember power select

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

in [ember power select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/) how to include default options for drop-down like "All" in  below
[image]

my service does't return "All" option.I think it not good to include it in the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it is not good to include additional options to store. Hence, you can just make use of a computed property. Please take a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/311b7526cfdf47dccad3addf6b1a2566?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). I created a computed property name `computedOptions` within `my-component.js` and inserted your custom option "All" as the first option to a new array copied from original `options` and just passed this `computedOptions` as `options` attribute of `power-select`.

Comment: btw is it good to include power-select in a component ? since I'm in initial stage of project development I need to follow ember standers.

Comment: of course, you can build your own component that makes use of a power-select. i personally use it in my own components heavily.

Comment: do you mind tel me how to set this All option as default option here.

Comment: I have updated the answer; you need to set `searchField` of the `power-select`. in this case; to `name`. Whenever; the options are of type json object you need to set the `searchField`.

Comment: you can set `All` as selected by default like I provided in the twiddle (I have updated it).